# Limit QKeySequence/QKeySequenceEdit to only one shortcut

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qkeyevent, qkeysequence

Is it possible to limit `QKeySequence` to show only one shortcut in `QKeySequenceEdit`? Currently now it supports up to 4 shortcuts. My application supports key sequences of only one shortcut, e.g. `Ctrl+A` or `Ctrl+C` and not e.g. `Ctrl+A, D` or `Ctrl+C, X, Z`.

Is it possible to limit `QKeySequence` or `QKeySequenceEdit` to just one key sequence?

Comment: What's the problem with QKeySequence supporting four keys? You're not forced to define four key shortcuts, are you? Just use them with two keys.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld No, I'm not, but it is a UX nogo to show the user four keys and use just one...

Comment: Where do such shortcuts show up in the UI if you don't define them?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld They appear in the `QKeySequenceEdit` I'm using. Not showing them there is also ok...

Comment: This seems more of a question about `QKeySequenceEdit` than `QKeySequence`.

Comment: @JonHarper Edited the question to reflect that better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it, not the best solution but quick...If you want something more customize, I think you have to build it yourself...

*customkeysequenceedit.h*:

```
#ifndef CUSTOMKEYSEQUENCEEDIT_H
#define CUSTOMKEYSEQUENCEEDIT_H

#include <QKeySequenceEdit>

class QKeyEvent;

class CustomKeySequenceEdit : public QKeySequenceEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CustomKeySequenceEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CustomKeySequenceEdit();

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *pEvent);
};

#endif // CUSTOMKEYSEQUENCEEDIT_H
```

*customkeysequenceedit.cpp*:

```
#include "customkeysequenceedit.h"

#include <QKeyEvent>

CustomKeySequenceEdit::CustomKeySequenceEdit(QWidget *parent) : QKeySequenceEdit(parent) { }

CustomKeySequenceEdit::~CustomKeySequenceEdit() { }

void CustomKeySequenceEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *pEvent)
{
    QKeySequenceEdit::keyPressEvent(pEvent);

    QKeySequence seq(QKeySequence::fromString(keySequence().toString().split(", ").first()));
    setKeySequence(seq);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just use the toString().split(", ").first() on the "changed" event. I couldn't add a custom element in the designer :(

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `[]` operator of `QKeySequence`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#operator-5b-5d

So in your interface constructor, write this:

```
connect(ui->editShortcut, &QKeySequenceEdit::editingFinished, 
        this, &dialog::truncateShortcut);
```

And add this private method to your dialog class:

```
void dialog::truncateShortcut()
{
    int value = ui->editShortcut->keySequence()[0];
    QKeySequence shortcut(value);
    ui->editShortcut->setKeySequence(shortcut);
}
```

Doing that, you fully respect the API and don't depend on the `,` character, which is quite risky.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers is to **truncate** shortcut **after the input done**. Anyway, it will **show more than one** shorcut in the **process** of inputing, which is kind of annoying.

I found a solutioin that **will not even show more than one shorcut**.

After one shortcut is inputed, finish the input via clear focus and `setKeySequence` via **override** `QKeySequenceEdit` class `keyPressEvent` function.

**What's more, this method is very easy and graceful!**

First create a class `myKeySequenceEdit` inheriated from `QKeySequenceEdit`, and below is the codes:

`mykeysequenceedit.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef MYKEYSEQUENCEEDIT_H
#define MYKEYSEQUENCEEDIT_H

#include <QKeySequenceEdit>
#include <QWidget>

class myKeySequenceEdit : public QKeySequenceEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myKeySequenceEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *) override;
};

#endif // MYKEYSEQUENCEEDIT_H
```

`mykeysequenceedit.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "mykeysequenceedit.h"

myKeySequenceEdit::myKeySequenceEdit(QWidget *parent) : QKeySequenceEdit(parent) {}

void myKeySequenceEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    QKeySequenceEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
    if (this->keySequence().count() > 0) {
        QKeySequenceEdit::setKeySequence(this->keySequence());
        
        emit editingFinished(); // Optinal, depend on if you need the editingFinished signal to be triggered
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on this: why would we like to wait in edit mode, if just singular shortcut is wanted. Thus interrupting edit immediately on success:

```cpp
inline bool QKeySequence_valid( const QKeySequence& accelerator ){
    return !accelerator.isEmpty() && accelerator[0] != Qt::Key_unknown;
}

class Single_QKeySequenceEdit : public QKeySequenceEdit
{
protected:
    void keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent *e ) override {
        QKeySequenceEdit::keyPressEvent( e );
        if( QKeySequence_valid( keySequence() ) )
            editingFinished();
    }
};
```

Real implementation, because i was struggling to find one of this sort:

```cpp
class Single_QKeySequenceEdit : public QKeySequenceEdit
{
protected:
    void keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent *e ) override {
        QKeySequenceEdit::keyPressEvent( e );
        if( QKeySequence_valid( keySequence() ) )
            clearFocus(); // trigger editingFinished(); via losing focus 
                          // because this can still receive focus loss b4 getting deleted (practically because modal msgbox)
                          // and two editingFinished(); b no good
    }
    void focusOutEvent( QFocusEvent *event ) override {
        editingFinished();
    }
    bool event( QEvent *event ) override { // comsume ALL key presses including Tab
        if( event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress ){
            keyPressEvent( static_cast<QKeyEvent*>( event ) );
            return true;
        }
        return QKeySequenceEdit::event( event );
    }
};

void accelerator_edit( QTreeWidgetItem *item ){
        auto edit = new Single_QKeySequenceEdit;
        QObject::connect( edit, &QKeySequenceEdit::editingFinished, [item, edit](){
            const QKeySequence accelerator = edit->keySequence();
            item->treeWidget()->setItemWidget( item, 1, nullptr );
            if( QKeySequence_valid( accelerator ) )
                accelerator_alter( item, accelerator );
        } );
        item->treeWidget()->setItemWidget( item, 1, edit );
        edit->setFocus(); // track sanity gently via edit being focused property
}
```